# Android 7.1 on QEMU (OpenNebula) - mouse integration

Tags: android, mouse, qemu, kvm, opennebula

I am having a problem with running Android 7.1 on a virtual machine inside OpenNebula (QEMU/KVM) - more specifically, a problem with mouse integration.

When creating a machine, I tried setting the input two ways:
1. Mouse/USB
2. Tablet/USB

In case 1. the mouse cursor is not in the location it should be (more to the left/right/up/down, depending on speed of mouse movement).
In case2. I have to hold left-click to move the cursor - this makes it move but also works as holding down the finger on touch screen.

My question is: is there a way to set the correct input type, so I can use the mouse normally when working with the system?

Info: It was not a problem in Android 4.4, where the Table/USB option worked correctly.

Comment: are you (or is OpenNebula, which I don't know what is) using noVNC?

Comment: OpenNebula is the cloud platform we use (not administered by us), and I think they are using noVNC.